# Integrating trig function

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

I'm stuck at this problem:

$$ \int{\sqrt{(\sin^2 x)^2 + (2\sin x \cos x)^2}dx} = \int{\sqrt{\sin^2 x \sin^2 x + 4\sin^2 x \cos^2 x} dx}$$

I tried a few trig identities: $\sin^2 x = \frac{1-\cos 2x}{2}  $ and $ \cos^2 x = \frac{1+\cos 2x}{2} $ and $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$. Keep hitting dead end. Any tips?

Comment: The answer doesn't look pretty according to [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%5BSqrt%5BSin%5Bx%5D%5E4%2B4Sin%5Bx%5D%5E2Cos%5Bx%5D%5E2%5D,x%5D).

Comment: Have you tried $\sin 2 x = 2 \sin x \cos x$ and $\cos 2 x = \cos^2 x - \sin^2 x = 2 \cos^2 x - 1 = 1 - 2 \sin^2 x$? (Hoping it's not a proper elliptic integral...)

Comment: @Ian Miller I tried symbolab and cymath, both couldn't work it out. I think wolfram's legit. When I input the upper and lower bounds, it gives the answer same from the answer sheet. $ 4 + \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \ln (2+\sqrt{3}). $ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%5BSqrt%5BSin%5Bx%5D%5E4%2B4Sin%5Bx%5D%5E2Cos%5Bx%5D%5E2%5D,x%5D+from+0+to+2pi

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\begin{align} &\int{\sqrt{\sin^2x \sin^2x + 4\sin^2 x \cos^2 x} dx} \\ &
=\int{\sqrt{\sin^2x( \sin^2x + 4\cos^2 x)} dx} \\ &
=\begin{cases}\int{\sin x\sqrt{( \sin^2x + 4\cos^2 x)} dx} & & & &, \sin x \geq 0 \\ -\int{\sin x\sqrt{( \sin^2x + 4\cos^2 x)} dx} & & & &, \sin x < 0\end{cases} \\ &
=\begin{cases}\int{\sin x\sqrt{(1 + 3\cos^2 x)} dx} & & & & & &, \sin x \geq 0 \\ -\int{\sin x\sqrt{(1 + 3\cos^2 x)} dx} & & & & & &, \sin x < 0\end{cases} \\ &
=\begin{cases}-\frac{1}{\sqrt3}\int{\sin x\sqrt{(1 + 3\cos^2 x)} d(\sqrt3\cos x)} & , \sin x \geq 0 \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt3}\int{\sin x\sqrt{(1 + 3\cos^2 x)} d(\sqrt3\cos x)} & , \sin x < 0\end{cases}\end{align}$$

Now say $z=\sqrt3\cos x$. Then the integration becomes

$$=\begin{cases}-\frac{1}{\sqrt3}\int{\sin x\sqrt{1 + z^2} dz} & , \sin x \geq 0 \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt3}\int{\sin x\sqrt{1 + z^2} dz} & , \sin x < 0\end{cases}$$

I hope you can finish it now, using the necessary formula. The formula can be deduced using integration by parts and proper substitutions and is denoted in the [linked page](http://www.sosmath.com/tables/integral/integ11/integ11.html) as no. 8.

[image]

Comment: When you took the $\sin x$ out of the square root, wouldn't that be valid only where $\sin x\ge 0$? So perhaps a plus-or-minus or the equivalent should be added?

Comment: @RoryDaulton Provided appropriate changes. Thanks for the feedback. Please check if it is okay now.

Answer (score 4):

Try a substitution with the last expression that you have

> $$\int\sqrt{\sin^4(x)+4\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)}dx\quad u=\cos(x)$$.

This leads us to the following integral where we do another substitution:

> $$\int\sqrt{3u^2+1}du \quad\!\! \text{substitute}\quad\!\! u=\sqrt{\dfrac{a}{b}}\tan (v) \quad\!\!\text{where}\quad\!\! a=1 \quad\!\!\text{and} \quad\!\!b=3$$

Then, the integral becomes the following:

> $$\int\dfrac{\sqrt{\tan^2(v)+1}+\sec^2(v)}{\sqrt{3}}$$

and the rest is more or less is using trig identities.

Comment: I think you meant $\times \sec^2(v)$ rather than $+\sec^2(v)$. Also you're missing your $dv$